# What is the difference between Object Data Type & Primitive Data Type?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to Java. And I have recently come to know that we can initialize same primitive data type as below:

```
Object name="Surendra";
Object age=27;
```

instead of

```
String name="Surendra";
int age=27;
```

What is the difference between these two definition and why/when should we use which one?.

Also, when we should `int` primitive data type and the `Integer` wrapper class.

Appreciate it if you can explain it in layman terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```java
Object name = "Surendra";
Object age = 27;  // Actually Integer here, not int
```

You are casting `String` and `Integer` to `Object`, which totally safe, since `String` is of course an `Object`, so is `Integer`. However, the following code won't compile, because even though `name` stores a `String`, java compiler have no idea about it. The compiler searches for a method called `trim` in `Object` class, and found nothing, so it refuses to compile. It's the same for `age`.

```java
name.trim();  // Won't compile
age.longValue();  // Won't compile
```

When to use `Object`? When you have no idea about the type as well. For example:

```java
public static void foo(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof String) {
        String s = (String) o;
        // ...
    }
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        Integer i = (Integer) o;
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can do an `instanceof` check and determine which operation to perform.

Talking about `Integer` and `int`, they are completely different. `Integer` is an `Object`, but `int` is not. `int` is a primitive type. You convert `int` to `Integer` by boxing and convert `Integer` to `int` by unboxing. Modern java compilers will do the boxing or unboxing for you. You mostly use `Integer` as a generic type parameter, such as `List<Integer>`. You can't use `List<int>` in java, since a type parameter must be an `Object`. Sometimes you also use `Integer` when you want `null` to be an valid value. Notice that when java performs auto unboxing on `null`, it will throw an `NullPointerException`. Be aware.

```java
// These 2 are identical
Integer o1 = 0;  // Auto boxing
Integer o2 = Integer.valueOf(0);  // Boxing

// These 2 are identical
int i1 = o1;  // Auto unboxing
int i2 = o2.intValue();  // Unboxing

Integer o3 = null;  // Works
int i3 = null;  // Won't compile
```